Fish shell error command line
I tried to use shell customization from fish, but after the installation is complete, every time I execute a command an error always appears like the screenshot.


What version of the fish shell are you using? AFAIK the --is-valid option was added to commandline in 3.4.0

You can try this solution:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fish-shell/release-3
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install fish

It work for me, hope work for you
